# Trying to check if int[] is empty Java

Tags: java, list, is-empty

Simple, I am trying to check if int[] distances is empty or not.

Why does this not work?

My Code:

```
int[] distances = {3,6,7,6,1,8,8,2,3,4,5,9};

    if(distances != null && !distances.isEmpty()) {
        throw new TransportException("No routes in entry");
    }
        else {

    return distances;
    }
```

Comment: Return error cannot find symbol - metho is Empty()

Comment: Please read a tutorial on array types.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `isEmpty()` method you can call on simple arrays. Just compare its length to 0.

```
if (distances == null || distances.length == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays don't have any method except the ones declared on `java.lang.Object`.

The only attribute they have is `length`, which is the length of the array. So you need

```
if (distances != null && distances.length > 0)
```

Read the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) about arrays. Or read an introductory Java book.

Comment: Assuming he wants to get into the body of the `if` clause when the array is either `null` or empty, this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, he just have to switch the if and else bodies. That's a bug the OP should be able to find by himself, and it's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(distances != null && !distances.isEmpty())
```

condition ensures that   :"Throw an exception when my array is not null and it contains some values.So it throws an exception whenever your array is NOT empty. I do not think that this is what you want.